# Creating a file system

Tags: installation, samba

I am attempting to learn about Ubuntu by creating a 13.04 SAMBA server. I have installed the basic server on one disk and created a LVG from 2 further disks. I have created a LV using all of the free space on the VG.

I am unable to install a file system.

`sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/group1/data` returns an error of "no such file or directory". `mkfs` does not appear in bin (should it?).

I then tried `sudo apt-get install mkfs` and, after building the dependancy tree and reading the state information, i get "unable to locate package mkfs".

Answer (score 10):

The mkfs program should be at /sbin/mkfs under Ubuntu; however it calls filesystem-specific subprograms depending on the *-t < type >* parameter e.g. mkfs.ext3, mkfs.ext4 and so on. In the case of xfs, that program (mkfs.xfs) is not installed by default but should be part of the xfsprogs package - so you probably need to install that, either via your favorite GUI package manager or

```
sudo apt-get install xfsprogs
```

Comment: @worked for me, using ubundtu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using a completely different syntax to what the man pages tell you to use.

```
sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/md0
```

Then I just mounted it using

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raiddrives
```